# Excel vba split function not working

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to get a number of character occurence in a string. It should work, but it doesn't.

```
Function countLetter(letter As String, secretWord As String)
    MsgBox (Split(secretWord, letter).Length)
    countLetter = Split(secretWord, letter).Length - 1
End Function
```

What is wrong here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Split` does not have a `.Length` property. Use `UBound` for a zero-based count of the elements in the array.

```
Function countLetter(letter As String, secretWord As String)
    MsgBox UBound(Split(secretWord, letter)) + 1
    countLetter = UBound(Split(secretWord, letter))
End Function
```

Comment: @Ans unrelated to the splitting, but notice the lack of parentheses around the `Message` argument passed to the `MsgBox` function; whenever you invoke a procedure without capturing its return value into a local variable, you should not have parentheses around the arguments. This **will** cause you problems one day or another.